# how to send new line in message (\n or <br/> tag) using sendMessage Method in asp.net C# using telegram bot API

Tags: c#, asp.net, telegram

I'm able to send messages using sendMessage method and I have read this telegram [document](https://core.telegram.org/bots/api#sendmessage) for better understanding but I want to send a message with new line like this below text

Ex:

```
Hi
How are you?
```

And I have tried the different ways, to send a message like above example using the below links.

```
https://api.telegram.org/bot5750055656:AAGNgj9lOMLoQG0lsjrKNhON0TEWoPdLNZU/sendMessage?chat_id=-724558134&text=Hi\n How are you?

https://api.telegram.org/bot5750055656:AAGNgj9lOMLoQG0lsjrKNhON0TEWoPdLNZU/sendMessage?chat_id=-724558134&text=Hi <br/> How are you?
```

I'm getting the messages in telegram like below

[image: Message in telegram incorrect]

But I want to send  message like below Image using sendMessage method

[image: Message in telegram correct]

Is it possible to send a message like 2nd image using sendMessage method?

Comment: Usually `Environment.NewLine` is enough to add line break to most of the environment. For eg: `Your_String+Environment.NewLine+Your_Next_Line_String`

Comment: Hi @maddy23285 thnx for your comment and It is working fine for me.